# How to use foreach loop on List type of class?

Tags: c#, foreach

Here is my class structure :

```
public class Emp_Details : IEnumerable
{
    public List<Employee> lstEmployee{ get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{        public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Emp_Details obj = new Emp_Details();
obj.lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
Employee objEmp= new Employee();
objEmp.Name="ABC";
objEmp.Age=21;
objEmp.Address="XYZ";
obj.lstEmployee.Add(objEmp);
foreach(var emp in obj)
{
              //some code
}
```

I want to use foreach on `List<Employee> lstEmployee` 
But I am getting

> Emp_Details does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Remove `: IEnumerable` - you're not implementing it.

Comment: You will also need to make sure `lstEmployee` is initialized before you use it. You may want to add a constructor to `Emp_Details` and do it there. Even setting it to an empty List would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are declaring in your syntax that your `Emp_Details` class implements `IEnumerable`, but you are not actually implementing it. You can simply remove the declaration and enumerate over the underlying list directly as others have suggested, or if you really want `Emp_Details` itself to be enumerable, you have to implement `IEnumerable`'s `GetEnumerator` method (simply return the inner list's enumerator):

```
public class Emp_Details : IEnumerable<Employee>
{
    public List<Employee> lstEmployee { get; set; }

    public Emp_Details()
    {
        this.lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Employee> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return lstEmployee.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

It's better to implement the Generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface implicitly and the nongeneric `IEnumerable` version explicitly for added type-safety. Now you can iterate over an instance of `Emp_Details`:

```
Emp_Details empDetails = new Emp_Details();
// add employees to the inner list
empDetails.lstEmployee.Add(new Employee(...));
empDetails.lstEmployee.Add(new Employee(...));
empDetails.lstEmployee.Add(new Employee(...));

// iterate over empDetails using foreach
foreach(Employee emp in empDetails)
{
    //
}
```

Also, since your `Emp_Details` class seems to be a collection, it makes sense to implement a collection interface too and expose `Add`, `Remove`, etc. methods instead of exposing the underlying `lstEmployee` directly.

Answer (score 5):

Simply remove the base interface from declaration of the `Emp_Details`:

```
public class Emp_Details
{
    public List<Employee> lstEmployee{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First time tried with that only. But it gave me exception that it does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: What is the exact exception text (or error message)?

Answer (score 0):

You must Implement Ienumerable's GetEnumerator method !

```
public class Emp_Details : IEnumerable
    {
        public List<Employee> lstEmployee { get; set; }


        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("You must implement this");
        }
    }
```